# Making Approval Comments Mandatory Without Code

Tags: approval-process

I know that it possible to set the approval comments mandatory using an apex code. I will be glad to know if there is a solution to make approval comments mandatory without using a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible without code.

There is an idea for this to happen. [Approval Comments Mandatory](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YKZdAAO)